# Value of radiated power from a black radiator at the peak of the spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

What is the value of the radiated power in the wavelength range of $\Delta\lambda = 100 nm$
from a black radiator of surface area $2.00 m^2$ at temperature $45^\circ$ at the peak of
the spectrum?